# quick question on an example of the derivative as a linear map.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

After reading many answers on the subject I feel like I am close to finally understanding why the derivative is a linear map. I think that if someone helps me understand the following example I might "get it"

So I have $f(x)= e^x$ then $f(x)' = e^x$ is not linear, but instead the function defined by $y \rightarrow e^x y$ is linear, but what is $y$? is it introduced for the sole purpose to have a linear map? Say that I fix x, then for different values of $y$ what am I computing?

So I should not call $f(x)'$ the derivative any more if the derivative is a linear map, then what should I call $f(x)'$?

Comment: No, I think in this case the "linear" refers not to the actual function identified as the derivative, but to the fact that (a) $\frac{d}{dx} 0 = 0$; (b) $\frac{d}{dx} a \, f(x) = a \, \frac{d}{dx} f(x)$; and (c) $\frac{d}{dx} [f(x)+g(x)] = \frac{d}{dx} f(x) + \frac{d}{dx} g(x)$.

Comment: @Monolite: what you are looking for is clearly spelled in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260084/22857).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think of the derivative (more properly the differential) as a rule that assigns a linear map to each point of the domain. This linear map approximates the change in the function’s value for a small displacement from that point.

In your example, you have the rule $f'(x)=e^x$. This rule assigns the map “multiply by $e^{x_0}$” to the point $x_0$. For any given value of $x_0$, this is multiplication by a constant, which is obviously linear. This linear map can then be used to approximate $f(x_0+h)$ by $f(x_0)+e^{x_0}h$. (I used $h$ instead of $y$ to avoid confusing a displacement from a point in the domain with a value in the function’s range.)

Comment: Thank you, I could not decide who to give the check-mark to, I feel like your answer was very important to my understanding also.

Comment: I think this is the only appropriate answer. It would be more complete if it included  [this explanation](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260084/22857).

Answer (score 9):

You are confusing the derivative of a function with the differential operator.

The derivative of a function is general is not linear, as you show: $f'(x) $ can be equal to $x^2$, $x^{29}$, $e^x$, etc, all non - linear function.

What is linear is the differential operator: this is NOT a function, is an operator that goes from a space of *functions* to another space of *functions*, very different^[1] than something like $x \mapsto e^x$ which is a function and maps *numbers* to other *numbers*.

So what it means in general for an operator (or a function) to be linear? It means that

$$f(ax + by) = af(x) + bf(y)$$

where $f$ is the operator, $a,b$ are numbers and $x,y$ elements in the domain of the opeator.

So if for a function $f:\mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R$ being linear means that

$$f(ax + by) = af(x) + bf(y)$$ with $a,b,x,y \in \mathbb R$ (and this then implies that $f(x) = ax + b$ for some $a,b$) for an *operator*  $L$ it means that

$$L(af + bg) = aL(f) + bL(g)$$ where $L$ is our operator, $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $f,g$ are functions in the domain of the operator.

Now if $L = \frac d{dx}$ is the differential operator that associates to a function its derivative, that is $L(f) = f'(x)$, then we say $\frac d{dx}$ is linear because

$$L(af + bg) = (af + bg)' = af' + bg' = aL(f) + bL(g)$$

Hope it's more clear now.

[1] Okay, it's not very different. Technically they are the same thing, just their domain are different (reals vs space of functions). It's good to keep in mind their distinctions though :)

Comment: A differential operator _is_ a function! Only, its arguments are not real/complex numbers or such, but themselves functions.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Indeed, you're right :) I wanted to remark the difference though! I tried to sacrifice a little formalism for the sake of clarity. (another point is that $a,b$ don't have to be reals but scalar in the field of the vector space where the functions live) Anyhow I edited

Comment: Actually, there are three different things that might be being confused: The derivative of a function, the differential operator, and the derivative of a function at a point viewed as a linear operator. This answer refers to the differential operator, which operates on functions, while amd's refers to the derivative at a point viewed as a linear map, which operates on displacements.

Comment: @filipos: that confusion only arises in the one-dimensional case; and even then, as amd mentions in his answer, the derivative is the coefficient of the linear term in the Taylor expansion.

Comment: This answer gets a downvote from me, as it completely ignores what the OP asked. The derivative as a linear map is a standard view in vector calculus exactly in the way mentioned by the OP. By the way, this information is [clearly spelled](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260050/are-derivatives-linear-maps?rq=1) on this site.

Comment: @filipos If I have to be honest, I don't understand how the derivative of a function at a point viewed as a linear operator is relevant. Okay, the derivative at a point represents the slope of the tangent line (so in this sense it's "linear") but so what? Everything is linear if you view it as $y \mapsto f(x_0)y$. When we say that something is linear (integral, derivative, etc) we are typically referring to the operator definition. But anyhow, it's just my opinion

Comment: @MartinArgerami See also my previous comment. I totally disagree, when we say "derivatives are linear" we refer precisely to the fact that they operate in the way I explained above. Again, for every function $f$ we can associate the linear map $y \mapsto f(x_0)y$. So what? Why is that significant? The explanation is Taylor's theorem that tells basically that it's a good approximation if we are close to $x_0$, but again, so what? How can this possibly be related to the phrase "derivatives are linear"?

Comment: I just wanted to make it clear that these two answers refer to different things, lest the OP be confused.

Comment: @Ant: it is very "possibly related" since it is the right generalization to higher dimensions.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Okay, I am not following you then. Please mention this generalizations and how is it all related. My point is (quoting from amd answer which you agree with): "The derivative is a rule that assigns a linear map to each point of the domain (So is every other function you can think of) This linear map approximates the change in the function’s value for a small displacement from that point. (okay, so we get that derivatives are the functions that approximate the function for small movements. Why are they called linear then?)".

Comment: @MartinArgerami  Another way of saying it would be: If $(f+g)' \neq f' + g'$ but the taylor expansion would still hold in the same way, would you call the derivative a linear operator? Really I'm struggling to see the connection, I'd appreciate an explanation of why you think so :-) Clearly I don't win to "win" the argument but understand your point of view

Comment: @Ant: because the derivative is the linear map that makes the approximation  $f (x+h)\approx f (x)+L (h) $ work. Properly, you define $L $ (for a given $x $) as the unique linear map such that $$\frac {\|f (x+h)-f (x)-L (h)\|}{\|h\|}\xrightarrow[h\to0]{}0. $$ This definition works with any pair of Banach spaces as domain and codomain. And this is what the OP was asking about.

Comment: @MartinArgerami So to recap: "-Why are derivatives called linear? -Oh you see, because they are the *linear* map so that this approximation hold". What you are saying is that we define linear maps in a certain way, but we only call derivative linear because not only they are linear, but they have (or are defined by) a certain property. That does not sound compelling to me. Maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: So a linear approximation is not compelling but the slope of the tangent is? The main point is that the classical definition of derivative stops making sense as soon as you increase the dimension of the domain to anything other than 1. The derivative as I defined it above does not have that problem, and lets you talk about differentiable functions in any dimension.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Not even the slope of the tangent, of course. Maybe we are talking about different things. Regardless of how derivatives are defined, I just said they're called linear because the operator that associates to a function it's derivative is linear. For example in $\mathbb R^n$ your $L(h)$ would be $L(h) = \nabla f \cdot h$ and my point is that the operator $\nabla$ is linear. I think I'm beginning to see your point but still it's unclear why one would prefer talking about linearity of $L(h)$ in $h$ instead of the operator defined by $L$

Comment: @MartinArgerami I just wanted to thank both of you for the discussion it was very beneficial to me, even filipos comment was.

Comment: @Monolite You're welcome :) discussions often clarify a lot of things :)

Comment: @MartinArgerami: why don't you just say _Jacobian_ instead of _derivative_? This could have avoided the entire confusion above. In the question you've linked to, IMO [Muphrid's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260261/11107) is much better than the accepted one.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Rudin calls it "derivative", Spivak calls it "derivative"; That's good enough for me. But, in any case, why wouldn't you want to use the word "derivative" for it? There is nothing to confuse it with. Also, "Jacobian" is used both for the linear map and for its determinant, which sounds confusing to me.

Comment: Well, there is something to confuse it with: the _differential operator_ “derivative”†. Which is IMHO a rather more useful thing to talk about, in the big picture, than just particular derivatives/Jacobians. Admittedly, _nabla_ is a generally understood name for this operator, which doesn't have the same ambiguity. I suppose it would make sense to use this name more consequently, even in the one-dimensional case.  —  —  —  †Note that always saying “differential operator” does not cut it, since there are plenty of differential operators apart from plain nabla.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be misunderstanding what is being called linear.

It isn't the function $f$ that is linear or not, it is the action of taking a derivative -- the differential operator $\frac d{dx}$ is linear in the sense that

$$\frac d{dx}(a\cdot f + b\cdot g) = a\cdot \frac d{dx}(f) + b\cdot \frac d{dx}(g)$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants and $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions. Linearity here means that the operator "distributes" across a sum of terms, and the multiplicative constants "pull through".

Comment: I'm afraid it's you who misunderstands : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260050/are-derivatives-linear-maps?rq=1

Comment: @MartinArgerami: I may have misinterpreted OP's question, but no context was given. My response, however, is completely correct. If OP was really asking about local linear approximations, rather than linearity of differential operators, then I indeed didn't address that. In that case, I would say the question is unclear. Moreover, the notion that I did address is commonly misunderstood by students first encountering the notion of a linear operator.

Comment: the second paragraph of the question clearly talks about the linear map $y\longmapsto e^xy$. What's unclear about that?

Comment: I chalked that up to a random stab, as it seemed to be reaching. Three of the four answers were essentially the same as mine, so I'm evidently not alone in thinking this. Moreover, one of those was the accepted answer. I do think that the comment by @filipos hits the nail on the head, though.

Answer (score 2):

The linearity of a system, map, function, etc. is tested by the superposition principle. For example, consider a function $f(x)$. It is linear if

$f(\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2) = \alpha f(x_1) + \beta f(x_2)$.

In this case, the derivative is also linear operator because

$D[\alpha y_1(x) + \beta y_2(x)] = \alpha D[y_1(x)] + \beta D[y_2(x)]$.

Comment: Nice answer. It might work better for the OP if you didn't use $f$ in both examples, and if you wrote the differentiation as an operator rather than with the prime.

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the very concrete question asked by the OP.