# Total derivative in multi-variable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I read the definition of differentiability as given in Tom M. Apostol's Mathematical Analysis as :
The function $f$ is said to be differentiable at $c$ if there exists a linear
function $T_c : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ such that
$f(c + v) = f(c) + T_c (v) + ||v|| E_c (v)$, where $E_c (v) \to 0$ as $v \to 0$.
There $T_c()$ is called a linear function and called the total derivative of $f$ at $c$, $c$ is a point in $\mathbb R^n$.
I can relate to the "error term" $E_c$ as I am familiar with Taylor's formula and this is a first order approximation of $f$. But I can't make a connection with functions in one variable. Is there a total derivative equivalent in one dimension? And also, everywhere on the internet this definition seems to be obscure and I only find total derivative defined as $df/dt$, like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative). What connection am I missing?

Comment: A $1 \times 1$ matrix is identified with a single real entry.

Comment: Tom has failed. Cash out and limit our losses before something worse happens.

Comment: @Randall can you elaborate please, I don't completely understand

Comment: Given $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and a point $\mathbf{v}$ in the domain, $df_\mathbf{v}$ is the linear map you mention, which is represented by an $m \times n$ matrix. That's the total derivative.  In single-variable calculus you say $f'(2)=4$ instead of discussing the matrix $df_2 = (4)$.

Comment: How is $df_\mathbf{v}$ linear? And how is $f'(x)$ linear? Eg. when $f'(x)$ = $x^2$, $f'(cx)$ = $c^2f'(x)$?

Comment: It is a linear map on $\mathbb{R}$, all of which are identified with where they send 1 (the "basis").  Maybe I'm not explaining this well and should stop. Sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are derivatives linear maps?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260050/are-derivatives-linear-maps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ (domain can also be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$).  We say $f$ is differentiable at $c$ if there exists a linear transformation $T_\mathbf{c}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that
$$
\lim_{\mathbf{h} \to 0} \ \frac{|f(\mathbf{c}+\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{c})-T_\mathbf{c}(\mathbf{h})|}{|\mathbf{h}|} = 0.
$$ 
This is equivalent to what you wrote.

At any rate, we write $df_\mathbf{c} = T_\mathbf{c}$ when it exists.  By definition, $df_\mathbf{c}$ is a linear transformation (input variable $\mathbf{h}$) and so is representable by an $m \times n$ matrix $A$.  In the general case this is the matrix of partials of the component functions.

In the 1-variable case, this is a $1 \times 1$ matrix, which is just a scalar and the ordinary derivative you're used to.

**Example:**  let $f(x)=x^2$ and let's examine $f'(3)$ (which will be 6, trust me).  The linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ via  $T(h)=6h$ satisfies my condition:
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \ \frac{f(3+h)-f(3)-6h}{h} = 0.
$$
(I don't need norms anymore since my $h$ is now a scalar, not a vector:  single variable calculus!)

Hence $T(h)=6h$ is the magic transformation, and as $T(1)=6$ we write the derivative as $f'(3)=6$, which is what you've always known from Calc I.

Comment: Oh yes, it all makes sense now!

Comment: Wow, really?  Great!  It took a looooong time for this to hit me when I first encountered it.

Comment: It took me quite long trying to understand it by myself before I posted the question here.